# OWIN ASP.NET - Avoid multiple logins for the same account without Identity in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

I want to know how can I block users to have multiple Refresh Tokens working at the same time. Let me explain:

- Some user ask for a new Access Token using Credentials.
- Credentials are okey, so the Authentication servers returns an Access Token and a Refresh Token.
- When Access Token expires, user have to use the new Refresh Token instead of Credentials to get a new Access Token.

The problem is that if another user log in using the same credentials, another Refresh Token will be generated for the same identity. So, what i want to do is: if somebody log in again using some credentials that have an active refresh token, instead of generating a new one, replace the existing one, or delete it and insert the new one. So the previous user will be disconnected when Access Token expires since Refresh Token wont exist anymore.

Also, how can i implement some service to destroy a Refresh Token in the Authentication Server? So the user can call it to disconnect his account, not just deleting the cookie and wait till it expires.

Here is my code:

**Startup.cs:**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,

            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/auth"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),

            Provider = new OAuthProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()
        });
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

**OAuthProvider.cs:**

```
public class OAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var account = AccountRepository.Instance.GetByUsername(context.UserName);
            if (account != null && Global.VerifyHash(context.Password, account.Password))
            {
                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, account.Username));
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("DriverId", account.DriverId.ToString()));

                var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, null);
                context.Validated(newTicket);
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

**RefreshTokenProvider.cs:**

```
public class RefreshTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public override Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var refreshToken = new TokenModel()
        {
            Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
            Token = GenerateToken(),
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
        };

        context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = refreshToken.IssuedUtc;
        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = refreshToken.ExpiresUtc;

        refreshToken.Ticket = context.SerializeTicket();

        try
        {
            TokenRepository.Instance.Insert(refreshToken);
            context.SetToken(refreshToken.Token);
        }
        catch { }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var refreshToken = TokenRepository.Instance.Get(context.Token);
            if (refreshToken != null)
            {
                if (TokenRepository.Instance.Delete(refreshToken))
                {
                    context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.Ticket);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    private string GenerateToken()
    {
        HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] byteValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        byte[] byteHash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byteValue);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteHash);
    }
}
```

One more question: how can i throw an Internal Server Error in the catch? Because it's actually returning `invalid_grant`, but the catch means a Database error, not invalid Credentials or Token.

Thanks for the help, and sorry for the bad english. I hope you understand!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

1. set access token expiration to small value (minutes / hours)
2. only issue a refresh token when user logs in using credentials (grant_type=password). This is a new refresh token.
3. store the 'new' refresh token *encrypted* in the database, replacing the 'current' refresh token.

You do not have to block users. The access token expires soon enough, just make sure you do not issue a new access token when refreshing the token. You can do this by checking the refresh token. If the encrypted refresh token doesn't match the encrypted refresh token in the database 'invalid_grant' will be returned. The user has only one option: log in again.

If the user logs in using credentials the refresh token is updated (also in the database). This will automatically invalidate the 'old' refresh tokens.

You can implement points 2 and 3 in RefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync. Some pseudo code:

```
// using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

public override Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
{
    var form = context.Request.ReadFormAsync().Result;
    var grantType = form.GetValues("grant_type");

    if (grantType[0] != "refresh_token")
    {
        // your code
        ...

        // One day
        int expire = 24 * 60 * 60;
        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(expire));

        // Store the encrypted token in the database
        var currentUser = context.Ticket.Identity.GetUserId();
        TokenRepository.Instance.EncryptAndSaveTokenInDatabase(context.Token, currentUser);
    }
    base.Create(context);
}
```

About the error, just return `invalid_grant`. how often do you expect the database to fail? The client will expect to login or either receive an 'invalid_grant'. It knows how to handle that (redirect to login page). The client doesn't have to know there was a database error. If you want additional information, you can log it in the backend.

Comment: So I should implement userId in the Refresh Tokens database, so every account will only have one active Refresh Token? I dont care if users gets a new Refresh Token when Refresh Token is used, because the old one is deleted, so the account will be closed only if inactivity is longer than Refresh Token life time. And about the error, i was thinking that isn't the same "Credentials Wrong" than "Server error". I'm going to consume this API from Android Device.

Comment: Yes, you should store the 'current' refresh token, but it doesn't really matter how or where you do this. You can for instance extend AspNetUsers with an extra field or add an extra table related to the AspNetUsers. Keep in mind that the user may never have to login again if refresh token never expires (since each time it is replaced with a new token with an extended expiration date). Make sure you build in an option to not issue a new refresh token in case you want to force the user to login again.

Comment: About the error. First of all, how often is this actually going to happen? If incidental, you can try to prevent this as much as possible by building in a retry. If that doesn't help, BaseValidatingContext has SetError to return an error message https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn343603(v=vs.113).aspx You can use this in your OAuthProvider class. But RefreshTokenProvider uses contexts that doesn't inherit from BaseValidatingContext. You cannot use context.SetError there. If storing the refresh token fails, retry or don't return a refesh token.

Comment: I think that you misread the title. I'm not using Identity. But it's okey, i can implement what you're saying. Is there anyway to extend `ClaimsIdentity` to add an Id property so I can use Id instead of Username? I know I could use a new claim but this way i dont have to convert it to string and back to integer. And the user will be disconnected if i delete his token in the database, so i dont think it's a problem. What about the logout service? Something like call ´/auth´ with ´grant_type=delete_token&refresh_token=xxxxxxxx´, can i do something like this?

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice idea. Im gonna build a retry, it will be enough, and if not the device can show the error as a timeout.

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't matter how or where you store it. It was just an example to give you an idea. You can use your own store. In fact the client cannot logout, but can 'forget' the tokens.

Comment: 'grant_type=delete_token' is not part of the specification. So you shouldn't use that.

Comment: You can add an extra claim, just build an extension to get the Id as int. Like .GetUserId() is an extension of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.